# Cmake suddenly can't find my source files anymore

Tags: cmake

To make a long story short:

[alt text http://www.uni-koblenz.de/~aheld/Cmake%20wears%20very%20dark%20sunglasses.png](http://www.uni-koblenz.de/~aheld/Cmake%20wears%20very%20dark%20sunglasses.png)

To add insult to injury, CMake actually ran fine several times. I was wrestling with a compiler error when CMake suddenly didn't feel like working anymore. For reference, here's the whole CMakeLists.txt file:

```
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

Find_Package ( SDL REQUIRED )
Find_Package ( SDL_image REQUIRED )
Find_Package ( SDL_mixer REQUIRED )

if ( NOT SDL_FOUND )
   message ( FATAL_ERROR "Make sure that SDL is installed" )
endif ( NOT SDL_FOUND )

link_libraries (
   ${SDL_LIBRARY}
   ${SDLIMAGE_LIBRARY}
   ${SDLMIXER_LIBRARY}
   SDLmain
)

set(wiggle_SOURCES 
        level.cpp
        levelgenerator.cpp
        main.cpp
        player.cpp
        scoreboard.cpp
        snake.cpp
        soundplayer.cpp
        titlescreen.cpp
    )

add_executable(Wiggle ../${wiggle_SOURCES})
```

The error occured for the first time when, instead of simply typing "make", I typed "make -lSDL -lSDL_image -lSDL_mixer" - make refused to find the header files SDL.h and SDL_image.h after I detached the project from Code::Blocks.

Answer (score 4):

This line:

```
add_executable(Wiggle ../${wiggle_SOURCES})
```

Would expand to:

```
 add_executable(Wiggle ../level.cpp levelgenerator.cpp main.cpp etc)
```

And that is probably not what you want. Also, I don't think your `level.cpp` file is in the parent directory, is it?